# diacritic letters in filename result with 404 error

Tags: iis, asp.net, url

I have two instances of my application. On one server I can get a photo like this:

> www.example.com/photos/Фото0139.jpg

and everything is ok.  But on the other one (and I know the same photo is there) I get 404 error.

It happens only if diacritic letters are in the file name. Does anyone know solution for that problem ?

Comment: Can you tell which version of IIS and Windows are you using for each server?

Comment: And which browser you use.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was settings of UrlScan ISAPI filter for me.

- Just go to "c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlscan\UrlScan.ini" file.
- Search for "AllowHighBitCharacters" value and set this value from "0" to "1".
- Restart IIS after saving the file.